# Custom action route inheritance in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, routes

I have the following controller inheritance chain (note that models do NOT inherit, but rather have a parent-child relationship): `EmployeesController < SitesController < CompaniesController`

I have an action, `companies#dashboard` that the subclasses inherit. Right now this is my routing:

```
  get "/company/dashboard(/:disguised_id)" => "companies#dashboard"
    get "/site/dashboard(/:disguised_id)" => "sites#dashboard"
      get "/employee/dashboard(/:disguised_id)" => "employees#dashboard"
```

But I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to set up this inheritance chain for a custom action?

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve with this inheritance chain?

Comment: more DRYing, for example if I change the exact route path at some point, I would want to change it the exact same way across all controllers (with the controller name appearing differently, of course)

Comment: You can do that through `routes.rb` without any inheritance, the routes are very configurable without any changes to controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [routing concerns](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#routing-concerns) to reuse sets of routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  concern :dashboard do
    get '/dashboard(/:disguised_id)', action: :dashboard
  end

  scope :company, controller: :companies do
    concerns :dashboard
  end

  scope :site, controller: :sites do
    concerns :dashboard
  end

  scope :employee, controller: :employees do
    concerns :dashboard
  end
end
```

Concerns can be included in `scope`, `namespace`, `resource` and `resources`. A better solution here would be to use namespaces together with a separate dashboard controller:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  concern :dashboard do
    get '/dashboard(/:disguised_id)', to: 'dashboard#show'
  end

  namespace :companies, path: 'company' do
    concerns :dashboard
  end

  namespace :sites, path: 'site' do
    concerns :dashboard
  end

  namespace :employees, path: 'employee' do
    concerns :dashboard
  end
end
```

This lets both lets you offload a responsibility from the normal controller which is already responsible for CRUD'ing the resource and use inheritance:

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  def show
    # do something awesome
  end
end
```

```
module Companies
  class DashboardController < ::DashboardController 
  end
end
```

```
module Sites
  class DashboardController < ::DashboardController 
  end
end
```

```
module Employees
  class DashboardController < ::DashboardController 
  end
end
```

Comment: Beyond that just remember that the routes are just a DSL -  not a declarative configuration format like YML or XML. You can use methods or even bake your routes into modules if you need to do more complex routing.

Answer (score -1):

I guess what you would like to do, is just DRY the routes, isn't it?

You might do that easier by having the only route for 3 resources. Let's say it would be "pages#dashboard". So you need the pages controller with dashboard. I use pages controller for landing pages, faqs, dashboard and e.t.c. So these are static routes that usually never changes. Because I won't delete dashboard, landing page, or FAQ section.

Then in dashboard you might render company_dashboard, site_dashboard or employee_dashboard depending on the resource.

And finally, you might have the only path in routes or do it like:

```
get "/dashboard", to: "pages#dashboard"
```

Of course, you might create another controller "dashboard" with "index" and serve the logic up there. But because I don't know your code or future design ideas, I might be wrong by advising the most easiest solution for me. But what I mean, is that probably you don't need 3 different controllers for dashboard.